# Error: Cannot find module 'transformer-module'

Tags: typescript

when I using ttsc command to compile the typescript project, shows error:

```
> yarn tscbuild
yarn run v1.22.17
$ ttsc

/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:111
    var err = new Error("Cannot find module '" + x + "' from '" + parent + "'");
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'transformer-module' from '/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel'
    at Function.resolveSync [as sync] (/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:111:15)
    at PluginCreator.resolveFactory (/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/ttypescript/lib/PluginCreator.js:158:34)
    at PluginCreator.createTransformers (/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/ttypescript/lib/PluginCreator.js:120:32)
    at Object.newEmit [as emit] (/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/ttypescript/lib/patchCreateProgram.js:76:52)
    at emitFilesAndReportErrors (/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/js-wheel/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:126134:23)
```

Am I missing something? I did not found the package named `transformer-module`. I have already installed ttypescript from the instructions from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ttypescript. what should I do to fixed this issue? the `transformer-module` was the plugin of ttypescript. it should be installed by ttypescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the examples provided by `ttypescript`, and the little information in your question.

I think you have misunderstood how the module works.

The `transform` key of the `plugins` object in your `tsconfig.json` file must be a relative or absolute path to your file. You probably keep the value `transform-module` specified on their documentation.

For example:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "declaration": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "plugins": [
            {
                "transform": "./src/transformers/transformer.ts" /* this line here */
            }
        ]
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*", "node_modules/ttypescript/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["src/transformers/**/*"]
}
```

Source: their examples (https://github.com/cevek/ttypescript/blob/master/packages/ttypescript-examples/tsconfig.json)

Otherwise, feel free to give more context such as a minimal reproducible example